# Erro de Integridade

Tags: python, django, assert

Tenho duas funções de teste onde o erro esperado é um AssertionError.

Contudo, o erro recebido é django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

A criação de um usuário ocorre 2x, mas os nomes não se repetem, pensei que pudesse ser esse o erro.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from parameterized import parameterized

from .test_recipe_base import Recipe, RecipeTestBase


class RecipeModelTest(RecipeTestBase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.recipe = self.make_recipe()
        return super().setUp()

    def make_recipe_no_defaults(self):
        recipe = Recipe(
            category=self.make_category(name='Test Default Category'),
            author=self.make_author(username='newuser'),
            title='Recipe Title',
            description='Recipe Description',
            slug='recipe-slug',
            preparation_time=10,
            preparation_time_unit='Minutos',
            servings=5,
            servings_unit='Porções',
            preparation_steps='Recipe Preparation Steps',
        )
        recipe.full_clean()
        recipe.save()
        return recipe

    @parameterized.expand([
        ('title', 65),
        ('description', 165),
        ('preparation_time_unit', 65),
        ('servings_unit', 65),
    ])
    def test_recipe_fields_max_length(self, field, max_length):
        setattr(self.recipe, field, 'A' * (max_length + 1))
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            self.recipe.full_clean()

    def test_recipe_preparation_steps_is_html_is_false_by_default(self):
        recipe = self.make_recipe_no_defaults()
        self.assertFalse(
            recipe.preparation_steps_is_html,
            msg='Recipe preparation_steps_is_html is not False',
        )

    def test_recipe_is_published_is_false_by_default(self):
        recipe = self.make_recipe_no_defaults()
        self.assertFalse(
            recipe.is_published,
            msg='Recipe is_published is not False',
        )
```

Comment: Esse módulo `.test_recipe_base` o que seria?

Comment: @AugustoVasques .test_recipe_base é a Base de Testes da minha aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de tentar resolver o problema, já que existe um author cadastrado é tentar utilizar o método first() para retornar a primeira ocorrência de um author. Esta solução pode ser aplicada caso o nome do ***author*** não seja relevante para o caso de teste.

Segue um exemplo de como deve ser implementado:

```
from .test_recipe_base import Author
Author.objects.first() # Substituir pela chamada make_author em seu código
```

Depois onde deseja utilizar um author você pode utilizar o model manager para "pegar" a primeira ocorrência de um author que está cadastrado na base de dados,  veja que este método não dá garantia de qual é o first() ele apenas é um helper que vai retornar a primeira ocorrência de um objeto que está na base de dados.

Enfim essa seria uma estratégia para evitar ocorrer o erro de integridade.

Se o dado do author é relevante para o teste, eu recomendo utilizar o método ***get*** para filtrar o username de um ***author*** específico. E pode ser implementado da seguinte forma:

```
Author.objects.get(username='newuser')
```

Como houve um erro de integridade creio que a coluna username é única e essa chamada deve resolver o problema de erro de integridade.

As sugestões feitas aqui estão documentadas na classe base [manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/) do Django.

Comment: Deu certo sua solução. Valeu!